# Magento 2 How to Upgrades schema

Tags: magento2, database

Magento 2 How to Upgrades schema

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Banner\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

        $installer->run('create table ud_banner(banner_id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(100), url varchar(100), image varchar(100), status varchar(100), primary key(banner_id))');


        //demo 
//$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//$scopeConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
//demo 

        }

        $installer->endSetup();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below code.. Hope it helps.

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Banner\Setup;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
    class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
    {
        public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            $connection = $installer->getConnection();
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
                $connection->addColumn(
                    $installer->getTable('review_detail'),
                    'reason',
                    [
                        'type'     => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'length'   => 1000,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default'  => NULL,
                        'comment'  => 'Reason for Not Approved Review'
                    ]);
            }
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
                $connection->addColumn(
                    $installer->getTable('sales_shipment'),
                    'custom_shipping_amount',
                    [
                        'type'     => Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                        'length'   => '12,4',
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'default'  => NULL,
                        'comment'  => 'Custom Shipping Amount'
                    ]);
            }
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is helpfull to you..

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;       
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;    
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface; 

class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface  
{  
    public function upgrade(
                 SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
                 ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {                
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0)
        {
            // Get module table
            $tableName = $setup->getTable('table name');

            // Check if the table already exists
            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true)
            {    
                $columns = [
                    'file' => [
                        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BLOB,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'comment' => 'approved request',
                    ],
                ];

                $connection = $setup->getConnection();
                foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
                    $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
                }
            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

if you have any query let me known.